# After doing a file_save_upload() how do you resize the images?

Tags: 7, media

I created a custom form in Drupal 7 with the ability to upload an image by using `file_save_upload()`. The image file has been uploaded and a fid has been assigned to it. How do I render this image into the different image styles I have setup?

Comment: i went and used image magick instead as i needed to overwrite the existing images during upload and resize. my answer has the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```php
print theme('image_style', array(
  'style_name' => 'your_style_name',
  'path' => $your_file->uri,
));
```

[theme_image_style](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21image%21image.module/function/theme_image_style/7)

Comment: what if i just wanted these resized images to be moved to a new folder?

Comment: What do you mean ? The resized images are already put in different folders based on there style name.
Like : sites/default/files/styles/your_style_name/

Comment: yes i know. but what if i want to rename these files and also move them to a new folder?

Comment: If you move a file from its style folder, it will be generated again on the next theme_image_style call.

Comment: anyway to just resize an image uploaded without theme_image_style() function?

Comment: If you don't want to do it the Drupal way, have a look at PHP GD or ImageMagick

Comment: @LeDrupaliste is correct. If you have created a style this is how you use that style for your image.

Answer (score 0):

I went and used image magick to generate the images vs using drupal core functions. Since I didn't have the image styles setup. I needed a way to generate these resized images and then place them in the proper folder with the proper name. First I create a form field for file uploading. And in the _submit function for the custom form. I have the following below. "file_thumb" is the name of my form file field.

**thfile** is grabbing the existing thumbnail filename so it can be overwritten with imagemagick.

**->writeImage** function will write the file to its new location.

```
//Generate new images for CUSTOM image file uploaded
$file_thumb = file_save_upload('file_thumb', array(), 'public://');

if ($file_thumb) {
  $thfile = $node->field_thumbnail[$node->language][0]['value'];

  $grid_thumb = new Imagick(get_absolute_file_root() . $file_thumb->filename);
  $grid_thumb->thumbnailImage(200, 200, true);
  $grid_thumb->writeImage(get_absolute_file_root() . 'grid-thumbnail/' . $thfile);
```